# Compiling C on Manjaro

Tags: compiling, c, manjaro, executable

First of all, I'm pretty new to the whole Linux world so sorry if this question may seem stupid.

I'm currently studying informatics and telecommunications, I tried Linux for the first time about 2 months ago and I'm enjoying it.

There's just one problem: I have to deliver on Google Classroom some C exercises that I compiled using NetBeans on Linux, but my teacher won't accept anything that isn't a Windows executable file.
What can I do to make an EXE on Linux?

I'm currently on Manjaro Cinnamon, thanks in advance!

Comment: have you encountered this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033997 ?

Comment: You'll want to  `pacman -S mingw-w64` and use mingw to cross-compile for Windows.  The link @Fox provided has details from that point on.

Comment: @Fox it worked!